# onClick submit para auth en firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, reactjs, react-hooks

Esta es la Pagina que hace el registro de los usuarios, nada del otro mundo, 
utilizo un par de Hooks, uno de reactfire y otro de react 
"useState" y "useFirebaseApp"

## Pagina donde esta el error

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import '../componentes/Estilos/PaginaRegistroEstilo.css'
import {useFirebaseApp} from 'reactfire';
import 'firebase/auth';

const PaginaRegistoUsuarios =() => {

  const firebase = useFirebaseApp(); 
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')


  const submit= async () => {
    await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    console.log(email,password)
  }

    return(
    <div className="container">
        <div className="jumbotron ">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-8">
                <h1 className="display-4">Registro de Usuario</h1>
                <p className="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-4">
                <img src="/public/logo192.png" alt=""/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label >Email address</label>
            <input type="email" className="form-control" 

            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label >Password</label>
            <input type="password" className="form-control"

             onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
          </div>
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={submit}>
            Completar Registro
          </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    )

}

export default PaginaRegistoUsuarios;
```

este es el index.js

```
import React, { Suspense, Fragment } from 'react';
import  ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; /* Boostrap Para manejo de estilos */
import App from './componentes/App';
/* Configuracion de Firebase */
import fireConfig from './firebase/fireconfig';

import { FirebaseAppProvider } from "reactfire";

const container = document.querySelector('#root')

ReactDOM.render((
    <Fragment>
        <FirebaseAppProvider fireConfig={fireConfig}>
            <Suspense fallback={'Conectando la aplicación...'}>{/* Este va permitir que se muestre informacion
            de carga en el caso de que app este procesesando la info de 
            firebase */}
                <App/>
            </Suspense>  
        </FirebaseAppProvider>
    </Fragment>



), container)
```

### App.js

este es el App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route, 
    Switch
} from 'react-router-dom'
/* Paginas */
import PaginaPrincipal_PAGE from '../paginas/PaginaPrincipalPage';
import PaginaRegistroPage from '../paginas/PaginaRegistroPage';
import PaginaAdministracionPedidosPage from '../paginas/PaginaAdministracionPedidosPage';

const App = () => {
    return( 

        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/PaginaPrincipal' component={PaginaPrincipal_PAGE}/>
                <Route exact path='/PaginaPrincipal/Registro' component={PaginaRegistroPage}/>
                <Route path='/AdministracionPedidos' component={PaginaAdministracionPedidosPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )


}

export default App;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en esta imagen aparecen tres cosas que no se que son y he tratado consultar pero no encuentro informacion que solvente mi problema, asi que agradeceria una ayuda, es mi primer desarrollo en reactjs y pues son problemas con los que no he lidiado

### #

uncaught exception: Object
The development server has disconnected.

Refresh the page if necessary. webpackHotDevClient.js:76

[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS... log.js:24

### #

Comment: El error te aparece solamente cuando haces click?

Comment: Si, ya cree una cuenta una vez, y despues de añadirla nunca dejo volver agregar ningun usuario mas